# Regex Validator Alphanumeric allow Empty fields but not Only Whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write an Regex validator that allows

only alphanumeric

- a-z, A-Z, hyphen, underscore, space, And Empty fields (no symbols !@#$% etc)
- however restrict a field with Only Whitespaces, (whitespaces allowed in beginning, middle and end if characters exist)

This seems to be working , just wondering if we can make it any cleaner.

```
/^$|(?!\s+$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$/
```

Trying to pass these unit tests:

```
  it('validator should allow alphanumeric characters', () => {
    formGroup.get(productName).patchValue('ABCabc1234');
    formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    expect(formGroup.valid).toBeTrue();
  });

  it('validator should not allow symbols', () => {
    formGroup.get(productName).patchValue('ABCabc@#$%1234');
    formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    expect(formGroup.invalid).toBeTrue();
  });

  it('validator should allow empty field', () => {
    formGroup.get(productName).patchValue('');
    formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    expect(formGroup.valid).toBeTrue();
  });

  it('validator should allow space among words', () => {
    formGroup.get(productName).patchValue('  ABC abc1234 xyz   ');
    formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    expect(formGroup.valid).toBeTrue();
  });

  it('validator should not allow all whitespaces', () => {
    formGroup.get(productName).patchValue('   ');
    formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    expect(formGroup.invalid).toBeTrue();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quantifier, `*` which means [zero or more occurrences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Also, [you can use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\w` in place of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

The final regex can be `(?!\s+$)[\s\w-]*` where `(?!\s+$)` specifies [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for one or more whitespace characters at the end of a line.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "ABCabc1234", "ABCabc@#$%1234", "", "  ABC abc1234 xyz   ", "    " };

        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches("(?!\\s+$)[\\s\\w-]*"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABCabc1234 => true
ABCabc@#$%1234 => false
 => true
  ABC abc1234 xyz    => true
     => false
```

Comment: whats the direct regex also?

Comment: this will allow symbols, !@#$%  which I want to disallow

Comment: @joecarl817 - No, it won't allow any of `!@#$%`

Comment: see unit tests above

Comment: Hi there, if you don't agree with the closing reason feel free to vote to reopen it. I think it is clear with the unit tests and the expected values.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the alternation, and write the pattern optionally repeating the character class:

```
^(?!\h+$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_\h]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\h+$)` Negative lookahead to assert not only horizontal whitespace chars
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-_\h]*` Optionally match any of the listed to also allow an empty string
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQl0gO/1)

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?!\\h+$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\h]*$";
```

Comment: see unit tests above, I have problem with space among words

Comment: and also with this ABCabc1234

Comment: @joecarl817 it matches right? https://regex101.com/r/TvvSpb/1

Comment: @joecarl817 You have to make the pattern case insensitive or else use https://regex101.com/r/dIouNW/1

Comment: It seems to [work](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd25k36r) fine for Java. Note that in my testing I swapped `[A-Za-z0-9_]` for `\w`.